# How can I reset the ThemeResource of DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have defined a DataTemplate that includes a textbox.  In "glove mode" I need a large font/minHeight so the touch screen works nicely, but in "office mode" I want different set of values.  I believe this should be possible, but can't figure it out.

How can I modify the theme in the code behind?  Or if this is totally wrong, how should I do it?

Styles:

```
<Style x:Key="GloveTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="60"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="OfficeTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="30"/>
</Style>
```

DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="InspectionItemStringTemplate" x:DataType="data:InspectionItem"><TextBox Text="{x:Bind NewValue,Mode=TwoWay}"
                     x:Name="MyTextBox" 
                     x:Phase="1" Style="{ThemeResource GloveTextBoxStyle}"/></DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

What about `IValueConverter`?
You can create something like that:

```
public class TextBoxStyleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Style GloveTextBoxStyle { get; set; }

    public Style OfficeTextBoxStyle { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {    
        // analyze binded value and return needed style
        return condition ? GloveTextBoxStyle : OfficeTextBoxStyle;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and in your XAML code

```
    <local:TextBoxStyleConverter x:Key="TextBoxStyleConverter">
        <local:TextBoxStyleConverter.GloveTextBoxStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30"/>
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="60"/>
            </Style>
        </local:TextBoxStyleConverter.GloveTextBoxStyle>
        <local:TextBoxStyleConverter.OfficeTextBoxStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="30"/>
            </Style>
        </local:TextBoxStyleConverter.OfficeTextBoxStyle>
    </local:TextBoxStyleConverter>


    <DataTemplate x:Key="InspectionItemStringTemplate"
                  x:DataType="data:InspectionItem">
        <TextBox Text="{x:Bind NewValue,Mode=TwoWay}"
                 x:Name="MyTextBox" 
                 x:Phase="1"
                 Style="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TextBoxStyleConverter}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```